# How do I use another custom portlet's service layer in Liferay 6.0.6

Tags: service, dependencies, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I have tried two things:

1. Specified the first portlet as a Required Deployment Context in the second portlet's liferay-plugin-package.properties.
2. Added the first portlet's portlet service jar to teh second portlet's web app libraries folder.

Neither worked.  I still get the ff. exception when I try a dynamic query on the first portlet's service.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.foo.bar.model.impl.MyPojoImpl
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
        at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.DynamicQueryFactoryImpl.getImplClass(DynamicQueryFactoryImpl.java:78)
        at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.DynamicQueryFactoryImpl.getImplClass(DynamicQueryFactoryImpl.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.DynamicQueryFactoryImpl.forClass(DynamicQueryFactoryImpl.java:33)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.java:23)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-13073.  Either upgrade plugin SDK to later than 6.0.5 or follow patching instructions in second comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the required deployment context from liferay-plugin-package.properties. After you are done creating service, move the your-service.jar in tomcat/lib/ext folder. Make sure none of your portlet has your-service.jar in its lib folder and then try calling the service.

Regards,
Sandeep

Comment: This won't work since this is the same as no. 2 in my original post.

Comment: Can you please tell me how are you using DynamicQuery, i mean the exact line of code

Comment: @Chry Actually no it's not the same as No.2, because Sandeep has said but the JAR on the tomcat classpath, not your portlet classpath (as you've tried).

Comment: @sandeepnair85, Sorry but I've lost the original code now.  Anyway, I've found the solution already.  It seems to be a Liferay bug.  See my answer.  Thanks for the help though.